# Prove injectivity

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Question:
Let $f: (0, 1) \times (0, 1) \to (0,1)$ be define as follows. For all
$(a , b) \in (0 ,1) \times (0, 1)$, we write $a = 0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots$ and $b =0.b_1b_2b_3\ldots $ using their infinite decimal expansions and put $f(a,b) = 0.a_1b_1a_2b_2a_3b_3\ldots $
show that f is injective.

To show that f is injective,
Suppose $f(a,b) = f(c,d)$ for some $(a,b),(c,d) \in (0,1)$. Then we have $0.a_1b_1a_2b_2\ldots = 0.c_1d_1c_2d_2\ldots $  And we need to prove $(a,b) = (c,d)$.
However, I’m stuck. I don’t know how can I prove $(a,b) = (c,d)$. At first I thought I could use the fundamental theorem of arithmetic, then I realized the FTA only works for integers that’s greater than 1.

I was wondering if anyone can give me some hint.

Thanks!

Comment: $a$ and $c$ have the same decimal expansion. How could they possibly be different? Minor caveat, though: the whole $0.999\ldots=1$ thing needs to be handled with care.

Comment: You can also pick $(a,b)\neq (c,d)$ and show $f(a,b) \neq f(c,d)$.

Comment: You must specify when two decimal representations are equal. We must decide whether $(a,b) = (c,d)$, but that means $a=c$ and $c=d$, so what is $a=c$?

Comment: @Arthur that’s true, but how can you show it mathematically? In a math proof you can’t just say”since they have the same decimal expansion they are equal”

Comment: @Qwert If two numbers, say $a$ and $c$, are different, then we have $\epsilon = a-c\neq 0$. Since $\epsilon \neq 0$, it must have a most significant digit. $a$ and $c$ must differ at that digit, or the digit before.

Comment: Correction of typo: equality $(a,b) = (c,d)$ means $a=c$ and $b=d$.

Comment: So, one way, as suggested is to define equality as 
$$\forall a,b\in (0,1)\quad a=b \overset{def}\iff \forall\varepsilon >0\quad |a-b|<\varepsilon  $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by Arthur, for equality we have for any $\varepsilon >0$
$$|0.a_1b_1a_2b_2\ldots - 0.c_1d_1c_2d_2\ldots |<\varepsilon.\tag{1}\label{1}$$
Assume \eqref{1} holds for some $(a,b),(c,d)\in (0,1)$. Let $\varepsilon >0$ be arbitrary. Our goal is to show $$|0.a_1a_2a_3\ldots - 0.c_1c_2c_3| < \varepsilon, $$
which is equivalent to $a=c$. Suppose, for a contradiction, $a>c$, then
$$a-c := 0.e_1e_2e_3\ldots >0 $$
What follows is
$$a = 0.e_1e_2e_3\ldots + 0.c_1c_2c_3\ldots =: 0.f_1f_2f_3\ldots$$
which yields
$$|f(a,b)-f(c,d)| = |0.f_1b_1f_2b_2\ldots - 0.c_1d_1c_2d_2|. $$

Because $0.f_1f_2f_3\ldots > 0.c_1c_2c_3\ldots$, there is the smallest index $n$ for which $f_n>c_n$ such that $0.\underbrace{0\ldots 0}_{n\ digits}c_{n+1}c_{n+2}\ldots >0$ and
$$|0.f_1b_1f_2b_2\ldots - 0.c_1d_1c_2d_2\ldots | > 0.\underbrace{0\ldots 0}_{n\ digits}c_{n+1}c_{n+2}\ldots,  $$
a contradiction to \eqref{1} taking $\varepsilon = 0.\underbrace{0\ldots 0}_{n\ digits}c_{n+1}c_{n+2}\ldots >0$.

Of course, similarly, one obtains $b=d$.

Answer (score 2):

If $$f(a,b) = 0.c_1 c_2 c_3 \ldots$$ then
$$a = 0.c_1 c_3 c_5 \ldots $$
and 
$$b = 0.c_2 c_4 c_6\ldots$$

That is the basic idea.  However all of this stuff needs
to work around ugly facts like $0.1000... = 0.0999...$.